# Procedural textures in materials mode Blender 2.79

Tags: animation, texturing, node-editor

I know. This question has been asked a lot. Most replies/responses I have found say it can't be done. And I feel I have been bamboozled.

It started with watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2WTH016rfk) tutorial on creating wormholes. At 34:30, he adds a noise texture and connects it directly to the output. On his, it displays the texture in the material viewport, in mine it doesn't. I am absolutely stumped to why his works and mine doesn't.

I am creating the wormhole on my MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015), which has a 1.6 GHz Intel Core i5 and an Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB. As the title states, I am using Blender 2.79. My OS is MacOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Because my computer lacks a GPU, I cannot use GPU rendering. I have no clue if it would effect material view or not.

All I know is this:

1. The node works on his computer in material view. On mine, it doesn't.
2. It works in render view
3. So far, everything else up to that point works a treat. No problems.

I know it is something to do with procedural textures overall.

Early thanks to the Blender community.

Cheers,

BFB

Comment: He's probably using Node Wrangler (a free add-on).  Pressing Ctrl+Shift+Click (might be slightly different on Mac) shows you just the effect of the node you click on.

Comment: I deleted my last comment. I was wrong, it still isn't working. The procedual textures just dissapeared. I am so stumped. They where working for 10 min, then it stopped. Any ideas?